# Generate a small as possible string that does not excist in MySql database

Tags: php, string, unique

I am trying to make a PHP script that generates a small string that does not excist in a MySQL database. If the string already is in use, I want it to generate a new number. I am going to use the script to make a URL shortener.

Comment: lolzzz, 7 days ago I started this project and stopped because it was so simple.

Comment: Use a primary key, autoincrement (and `dechex()`).

Comment: Convert the id to a higher radix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use google's shortener API? https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/

If you wanna do it by yourself, there is a really cool (and simple for PHP beginners) implementation - tutorial [here](http://www.johnboy.com/blog/how-to-write-a-url-shortener-script-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use auto-increment in your database to have a unique id assigned to all entries. You would then take this id and convert it to a higher radix (using php's `base_convert` I suppose). You could, for example use base 62 (will optimally use alphanumeric characters). Some example code:

```
<?php
$id = getId(); // Depending on the database interface you're using (eg. PDO)
$short_suffix = base_convert($id, 10, 62); // From base 10 to base 62
$short_url = "http://yourwebsite.tld/$short_suffix";
```

One advantage here is that you only have to store an id and an url for each entry (instead of the shortened URL as well).